# Showing that if $f$ is right continuous at $c$, then $f(x)>0$ in some neighborhood of $c$.

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

If a function is right continuous at $c$, and $f(c) >0$ then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that  $f(x) > 0$ for some $c \leq x \leq x+\delta$.

PLEASE someone help me to prove this I've been staring at it for hours! thanks!

Comment: I edited this, please make sure that this is indeed what the question is asking

Comment: It would be better if you add some context saying where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Andres, yes thank you.  Well, I have to write the proof, and can't quite get it started...

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\epsilon=\frac{f(c)}{2}>0.$ Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon=\frac{f(c)}{2}.$$ That is, $$f(x)> \dfrac{f(c)}{2}>0, \forall x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta).$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is right continuous, this means that there exists some $\delta$ so that $|x-c|<\delta$ and $x>c$ implies that $0 \leq|f(c)-f(x)|<\frac{f(c)}{2}$. But then pick some $x$ so that $|x-c|<\delta$ and $x>c$. But then $f(x)$ is within $B(f(c), \frac{f(c)}{2})$ which is always greater than zero by construction.